# How to force Postgres to calculate with numeric precision

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a .net core application using dapper with Postgresql.
Windows, PostgreSQL 12.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

When i do simple calculation in the select-statement, then i get different results if i do not provide fractions:

```
select round(25358-25358/105*100,0);
```

> 1258

```
select round(25358.0-25358.0/105*100,0);
```

> 1208

What's the reason and what's the best way to get correct numeric result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres, as many other databases (SQL Server for example), does integer division: when both operands are integers, the result is an integer as well (the decimal part is just dropped).

Both operands to `25358/105` are integers, so the result is `241`.

On the other hand, `25358.0/105` has a decimal operand, so the result is decimal: `241.504...`.

The rest of the computation is affected accordingly.

```
select 25358/105 integer_divison, 25358.0/105 decimal_division
```

```
integer_divison |     decimal_division
--------------: | -------------------:
            241 | 241.5047619047619048
```